# How to evaluate Vue.js component props in the data property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 2 components: `Post` and `Comments`.

Inside Post component, there is Comments component that has 3 props: `postId`, `numCom` (number of comments) and `comments` (array).

I get comments and I pass the array with props, and now I want to retrieve the array in Comments component and add it to data so I can then add/remove comments etc.

Here is my code in `Comments.vue`:

```
props: ['id', 'numCom', 'comments'],
data: function() {
  return {
     newMessage: "",
     loading: false,
     allComments: this.comments,
     num: this.numCom,
   }
},
```

But this doesn't works. In Vue developer tools I can see that `comments` prop is filled with comments, but `allComments` array is empty.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure that the `comments` prop has a value at the time the component is created?

Comment: We'll need to see more code because I threw together an example and its working for me. https://jsfiddle.net/7xxwq1e2/18/

Comment: @DecadeMoon yeah, there is a little delay, because I am doing GET request, then filling the props... How should I solve this? I could do a GET request inside Comments component, but how could I trigger a function in Comments component from Post controller when I display a new post?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like the `comments` prop does not have a value at the time of the component's creation (which is the only time `allComments` will be set).

You can either:

1. Defer the creation of the component until the `comments` prop is ready by using `v-if` like this:

```
<comments v-if="comments" :comments="comments"></comments>
```

2. Watch for changes to the `comments` prop and set `allComments` to the new value (in addition to initializing `allComments` in the data function):

```js
watch: {
  comments(value) {
    this.allComments = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use computed properties

```
computed: {
  allComments () {
    return this.comments
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to put the props into data, just use `this[propName]` to get the value.

If you want to change a prop value or key to another value,just use `computed` to change it.