# vuejs: How can I make my data react to props change?

Tags: vue.js

I've got basic vue props and data:

```
props: ['person', 'type']
data() {
  return {
    offer: {
      type: 'basic',
      person: 'nurse',
      ...
```

How can I make my data react to props change? For example if prop `person` will be `'physican'` I want my data `offer.person = 'physician'`. Oherwise if props value will be empty, I want to have default value of `offer.person`.

How is the easiest way to achieve this? I tried watchers, computed, but none of them seems to work.

edit:
I wrote something like this:

```
  basicComputed(){
    this.offer.person = this.person
    this.offer.type = this.type      
  },
```

and then in template:

```
<template>
  <div>
     {{basicComputed}}
  </div>
</template>
```

It works, but it seems that it is not a perfect solution. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You can use `props` directly in your templates if that's what you are looking for. If you do want to use this in the `offer` variable you might have to look into watch/computed properties (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022705/vue-js-passing-props-to-data)

Comment: @Teun this is a good idea to use watchers, but what will happen if parent component rerender. This is something like "crate new" component - take a value at start and don't change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your props to an object and you can use defaults

```
props: {
  person: {
    default: "some role"
  },
  type: {
    default: "basic"
  }
}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation

Comment: thanks for this tip! can I modify this to be an element of offers object?
just like: `props: { offer.person: { default: "some role" },`

Comment: then why not just have `offer` as the prop? so `props: { offer: { default: {person: "some role", type: "basic" } } }`

Comment: that's because I use offer array as a placement for my api requests